# How to see that this is a null sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I see/ prove that $(a_n) $ with
$$
a_n:=\frac {n^2}{2^n}
$$
is a null sequence?

Do not see how to estimate.

$$
a_n\leq n^2/2
$$

But this does not help at all.

Comment: Hint: $2^n=\exp(n \log 2)$

Comment: Are you allowed l'Hopital's Rule?

Answer (score 2):

By the Binomial Theorem, or otherwise, we have
$$(1+1)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\cdots +\binom{n}{n}.$$
For $n\ge 3$, it follows that
$$2^n \gt \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}.$$
It is not difficult to show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2}{(n)(n-1)(n-2)/6}=0.$$